# Moving sum text to the extreme right in amcharts serial graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

**[Problem Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g3x1mmy0/2/)**

Below is the code am using to construct `serial graph` with **[amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/)** plugin. I have referred this **[`demo`](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/add-automatic-sum-labels-top-stacked-columns/)** to add `sum text`, but the only difference is that in `demo` it is vertical graph and I've used `rotate=true` option to make it `horizontal graph`. In demo mentioned above, the `sum text` will be at top, but the issue am facing here is the `sum text`, comes within label. I would like to append it to extreme right after the last `bar`. Also, I would like to hide the `sum text` if its `0`. But I did not find any suitable option for this anywhere in the docs or SO. Could anyone guide me in the right path?

```
var data = [{
  "name": "Test1",
  "firstAmount": 0,
  "secondAmount": 0,
  "thirdAmount": 0,
  "forthAmount": 0,
  "total": 0
}, {
  "name": "Test2",
  "firstAmount": 4164,
  "secondAmount": 1232,
  "thirdAmount": 0,
  "forthAmount": 0,
  "total": 5396
}, {
  "name": "Test3",
  "firstAmount": 2509,
  "secondAmount": 0,
  "thirdAmount": 0,
  "forthAmount": 0,
  "total": 2509
}, {
  "name": "Test4",
  "firstAmount": 9909,
  "secondAmount": 200,
  "thirdAmount": 330,
  "forthAmount": 222,
  "total": 10661
}]
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  // iterate through data
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];

    dp.total = 0;
    dp.totalText = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < chart.graphs.length; x++) {
      var g = chart.graphs[x];
      dp.totalText += dp[g.valueField];
      console.log(dp[g.valueField])
      if (dp[g.valueField] > 0)
        dp.total += dp[g.valueField];
      if (dp.total == 0) dp.total = "";
    }
  }
  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.valueField = "total";
  graph.labelText = "$ [[totalText]]";
  graph.visibleInLegend = false;
  graph.lineAlpha = 0;
  graph.showBalloon = false;
  graph.fontSize = 13;
  chart.addGraph(graph);
}, ["serial"]);
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  //"theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": data,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>$ [[firstAmount]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#fdaa29",
    "valueField": "firstAmount"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>$ [[secondAmount]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#45aeea",
    "valueField": "secondAmount"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>$ [[thirdAmount]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#8fc842",
    "valueField": "thirdAmount"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>$ [[forthAmount]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#d43a43",
    "valueField": "forthAmount"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  }],
  "rotate": true,
  "columnWidth": 0.8,
  "categoryField": "name",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ry1dsoLa/

You have to use:

```
graph.labelOffset = 5;
graph.labelPosition = "right";
```

To position it on the right side.

To remove the 0 label, you can use the `graph.labelFunction`

```
graph.labelFunction = function(item, label) {
    return label == "$ 0" ? "" : label;
};
```

You do not need the for loop, because you already have a `total` in your data set.

However, you can also just add the graph now to the `graphs` array, without the need of hooking into the `init` function.

Like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ry1dsoLa/1/

Comment: Buddy.. If you notice, the label takes time to appear, may be 3-5 secs.. How would I make it appear instantly?

Comment: Yes, that was my issue as well.. I'll see what i can do about that :D

Comment: It's because of the `startDuration`. If you set it to `0`, everything is there immediately.. but without the animation. I think it is a little bug with amcharts. Because the graphs are stacked, they combine it to 1 animation. But because there are 4 stacked graphs, the 5th graph (label), won't show after 4 seconds.

Comment: Oh yea.. :) I can reduce it upto 0.3 or 0.4.. Slight animation is fine for me.. :) I have 2 more requirements... Will try my best and if I cannot, then will post a question.. :)

Comment: This is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xjvx85wn/), where you got a 1 second animation, with immediate appearance of the label, and with the colours you want ;)

Comment: Wow.. What is that option you set there?? :o

Comment: gotcha.. :) You moved sum label to the top of the graph right? :) Awesome bro.. :) Really amazed.. :)

Comment: That's indeed what i did :)

Comment: Once again.. Thanks much bro.. :) +1 +1.. ;)

Comment: Buddy?? You there?? :) Stuck on an issue again.. :(

Comment: Any help with this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868003/amcharts-numberformatter-doesnt-apply-for-serial-chart

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved it.. :) There is an option called `graph.labelPosition`, which was valued as `top` and I've made it to `right` and to remove `0` total from list, I've just emptied its text if it was `0`. Below are the changes:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  // iterate through data
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];

    dp.total = 0;
    dp.totalText = 0;
    dp.totalSymbol="$"; //added currency here
    for (var x = 0; x < chart.graphs.length; x++) {
      var g = chart.graphs[x];
      dp.totalText += dp[g.valueField];
      if (dp[g.valueField] > 0)
        dp.total += dp[g.valueField];
      if (dp.total == 0) {
           dp.total = "";dp.totalText="";dp.totalSymbol=""; //empty everything
      };
    }
  }
  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.valueField = "total";
  graph.labelText = "[[totalSymbol]] [[totalText]]";
  graph.visibleInLegend = false;
  graph.lineAlpha = 0;
  graph.labelPosition="right";//set label to extreme right
  graph.showBalloon = false;
  graph.fontSize = 13;
  chart.addGraph(graph);
}, ["serial"]);
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g3x1mmy0/4/)**

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc.. Still am gonna take ua answer.. :) Thanks for coming whenever in need.. :)

Comment: Thanks! Glad i could help again :)

Comment: And your solution is awesome again.. :) Removes lot of redundant code.. :)

Comment: Updated the answer a little more